# Wallet Objects API 503 "maximum retries exceeded"

Tags: android-pay

503 "maximum retries exceeded" error -- what does this mean?

Failed to create an instance through signup due to:
An error occurred:code: UNAVAILABLElocation: .http status: 503Service is not available[debug] APPLICATION_ERROR;/LoyaltyApiService.SignupAccount;com.google.commerce.wobs.common.exceptions.ExternalServiceException: Unable to make request: Method: POST failed: maximum retries exceeded: Test-Program-283927136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we hit the merchant's webservice, we time out after 10s and retry up to 3 times.  The "maximum retries exceeded" error appears if we've tried to hit your webservice 3 times but failed.
There could be multiple reasons for this. One could be simply that your webservice is not responding. Another cause is an error in your SSL certificate chain if you are using HTTPS (which you should be).